# Re-arranging/grouping lines with same arguments in bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to re-arrange some lines with a bash script.

Input:

```
Name1 127.0.0.1
Name2 127.0.0.2
Name2 127.0.0.5
Name2 127.0.0.8
Name3 127.0.0.3
```

Output:

```
Name1 127.0.0.1
Name2 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.5, 127.0.0.8
Name3 127.0.0.3
```

Is there a smart way to do this with 'awk' or 'sed' etc? Thanks!

Comment: It would be fairly easy to write a program in [tag:awk] to do this. If you're not comfortable in `awk`, write it in whatever language you're most comfortable.

Comment: Example: cat test_data | awk '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]?arr[$1]", "$2:$2} END { for (var in arr) print var" "arr[var] }'

Answer (score 1):

This one works with `bash`. It picks up all IPs and groups them by the appropriate names

```
declare -A ips

while read name ip; do
    if [ -n "${ips[$name]}" ]; then
        ips[$name]="${ips[$name]}, $ip"
    else
        ips[$name]="$ip"
    fi
done

for i in "${!ips[@]}"; do
    echo "$i ${ips[$i]}"
done
```

You can call it with

```
bash script.sh <input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is the programmatic way I've also did. I just prefer the solution from XzKto above - an elegant one-liner ;-)